# exam with timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate it if you can help me with this program. I would like the program to run ike this:

1. upon clicking a button, a question like 3 X 2 will be written in the document with a textbox wherein I can put the answer.
2. check if the answer is right or wrong using a promptbox.
3. It should have a timer that goes from 60 to 0 and when it reaches zero and you weren't able to answer it, then it will prompt you that the time is up.

I figured out the countdown timer already. I just don't know how to create the rest ^_^.

it would be great if you can incorporate it with my codes that i have figured. here is my code so far..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Timer</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var SECONDS_LEFT, TIMER, TIMES_UP;

function resetTimer(seconds){
 SECONDS_LEFT = seconds;
 document.Timer.TimeLeft.value = SECONDS_LEFT;
 clearTimeout(TIMER);
}

function decrementTimer(){
 TIMES_UP = false;
 document.Timer.TimeLeft.value = SECONDS_LEFT;
 SECONDS_LEFT--;


 if (SECONDS_LEFT >= 0) {
  TIMER = setTimeout(decrementTimer, 1000);
 } else {
  alert("Time's up!");
  resetTimer(60);
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="resetTimer(60)">

<form name="Timer" onsubmit="return false;">
Timer: <input type="text" name="TimeLeft" size="2"
  style="text-align:center" onfocus="this.blur();">
  seconds left<br>
  <input type="button" name="btnStart" 
   value="Start Quizz" onclick="decrementTimer();">
  <input type="button" name="btnReset" 
   value="Retry" onclick="resetTimer(60);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can read-up on Document-Object Model as well as arrays and generating (pseudo) random values. Try yourself on those and you should be on your way to creating your questionnaire.

Comment: Be aware that anybody facing this question can just reset the timer or increase the time if they want to.

Comment: yeah i know.. i just want the questions to come out when i click on start the quizz. it doesn't have to be a random number it can be a static question that has a fixed answer written in the code. I just need something to start on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store the question and answers in a multidimensional array like follows

```
// [question number, answer, question]
var qanda =[ 
[1,15,"Add 11 + 4"],
[2,7,"Add 4 + 3"],
[3,7,"Subtract 9 - 2"]
];


function getQuestion(n){


document.getElementById("disp_question").innerHTML = qanda[n][2];

document.getElementById("intp_div").style.display = "block";

}

function checkAnswer(n){


if(document.getElementById("intp_answer").value != undefined){

if(document.getElementById("intp_answer").value == qanda[n][1]){

alert("correct")

    }else{
   alert("incorrect")
    }

}
}
```

And you could add this below your retry button

```
<div id="intp_div" style="display:none">
<h3 id="disp_question"></h3><input id="intp_answer" type="text" value=""><input type="button" value="Submit Answer" onclick="checkAnswer(2)" />
</div>`
```

this it just to hepl you get on your way Note:

`onclick="checkAnswer(2)"` the "2" is the question your refferencing from the q and a array

Comment: This just hit me from my earlier comment. You can generate a more unpredicatable set of questions relying only on (pseudo) random numbers and not even using arrays.

Comment: Thank you.. I've figured it out already but I appreciate the time.

Comment: @Ibanez1942 Cheers, Im happy that you worked it out well done!